# Finding the General Solution of a Linear System in Compact Form

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, cross-product

Consider the following two vector equations

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}) &= \mathbf{b}_1 \tag{1}\\
\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} \phantom{)} &= \mathbf{b}_2 
\tag{2}
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}_1$ and $\mathbf{b}_2$ are known vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are unknowns which we wish to find. Here are my questions

> - Does this system have a unique solution?
> - Can we obtain a compact formula for $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$?

**My Thought**

I think that due to the presence of  cross product, having a unique solution is too much to expect! For finding a compact formula, the difficulty lies in finding all of the solutions of $(1)$ by thinking of $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}$ as a single unknown and thinking of $(1)$ as a linear systems of equations. After finding $\mathbf{x-y}$ from the first equation, it will be straight forward to find $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ by simply adding and subtracting the equations. However, I don't know how to present the general solution of $(1)$ in a compact form. Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Solve the second equation for $y$ and substitute in the first equation and your question reduces to solving $a\times x = c$ for some given vector $c = c(b_1,b_2)$. 1) Since $a\cdot (a\times x) = 0$ we see that only when $c$ is perpendicular to $a$ ($a\cdot c = 0$) can there be a solution. 2) Since $a\times a = 0$, if $x$ is a solution then so is $x + ka$ for any real number $k$.

Comment: @Winther: Thanks for the attention. Suppose the perpendicularity condition is satisfied then how do you express $x$ in terms of $a$ and $c$?

Comment: @Winther: I think that I got the idea from your observations! We can find a special solution of $(1)$ that is perpendicular to both $a$ and $c$. Then we add any multiple of $a$ to it and we get the general solution. :)

Comment: I think you can find a particular solution by considering $a\times(a\times x) = a\times c$ (use cross-product identities on the left hand side).

Comment: @Winther: How should I find $x$ from this? :) Using $bac-cab$ gives $(a \cdot x) a - |a|^2 x$.

Comment: Try assuming $a\cdot x = 0$ and see where that leads you. This gives me something like ${\bf x} = k {\bf a} - \frac{{\bf a}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot {\bf a}}$ where ${\bf c} = \frac{{\bf b_1} + {\bf a}\times {\bf b_2}}{2}$ under the condition ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf b_1} = 0$. Not 100% sure if this is the most general solution though (I'm too tired to think properly tonight).

Comment: @Winther: That is what told in my previous comments and forgot it in just a minute! :D Thanks Winther. Everything looks OK now. :)

Comment: @Winther: Would you please write an answer so that I can accept it? :) I do appreciate your attention and discussion. :)  (From geometrical intuition, it looks like that what you obtained is the general solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the second equation for ${\bf y}$ and substituting into the first one gives us

$${\bf a}\times{\bf x} = {\bf c}~~~\text{where}~~~{\bf c} = \frac{{\bf b_1} + {\bf a}\times {\bf b_2}}{2}$$

Now since ${\bf a}\cdot ({\bf a}\times {\bf x}) = {\bf x}\cdot ({\bf a}\times {\bf x}) = 0$ we have ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf c} = {\bf x}\cdot {\bf c} = 0$ so ${\bf c}$ has to be orthogonal to both ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf x}$. This is satisfied only when  ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf b_1} = 0$. By assuming that ${\bf a} \cdot {\bf x}=0$ we can get

$${\bf a}\times{\bf c} ={\bf a}\times ({\bf a}\times {\bf x}) = ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf x}) {\bf a} - ({\bf a} \cdot {\bf a}) {\bf x} = -{\bf x}\|{\bf a}\|^2$$

and hence we find

$${\bf x} = - \frac{{\bf a} \times {\bf c}}{\|{\bf a}\|^2}$$

Finally if ${\bf x}$ is a solution then so is ${\bf x} + k{\bf a}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{R}$ so the most general solution is

$${\bf y} = {\bf b_2} - {\bf x}~~~\text{with}~~~{\bf x} = k{\bf a} - \frac{{\bf a} \times {\bf c}}{\|{\bf a}\|^2}~~~\text{when}~~~{\bf a}\cdot {\bf b_1} = 0$$

Comment: Alternative derivation: When ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf c} = 0$ we have that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is spaned by the three orthogonal vectors $({\bf a},{\bf c},{\bf a}\times {\bf c})$. Taking ${\bf x} = k {\bf a} +\beta {\bf c} + \gamma ({\bf a}\times {\bf c})$ and inserting this into ${\bf a}\times {\bf x} = {\bf c}$ gives us $\beta = 0$ and $\gamma = - \frac{1}{\|a\|^2}$ leading to the same solution.

Comment: The alternative seems nicer! :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $\vec a=(a_x,a_ya_z)^T$ and $\vec b=(b_x,b_yb_z)^T$ we can represents the cross product in matrix form as:
$$
\vec a\times \vec b=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-a_z&a_y\\
a_z&0&-a_x\\
-a_y&a_x&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_x\\b_y\\b_z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but note that the matrix is singular, so  the existence of a  solution of $\vec a \times \vec b = \vec c$ is not guaranties and, in fact, exists only if $\vec c$ is orthogonal to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, as noted in the comment of Winther.

Comment: Assume the perpendicularity condition is satisfied then how do we proceed to express the general solution? :)

Comment: $\vec b $ is a vector in the plane that contain $\vec a$ and orthogonal to $\vec c$ and such that  the angle $\theta$ between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is such that $\sin \theta= |\vec c|/(|\vec a||\vec b)|$.